# How should the form control buttons be arranged?

Tags: forms, buttons, controls, page-control

Where is the best place to show form actions in a system (CRUD buttons*)?  I have currently placed them in a sticky header that follows a user down the page so as to always show the controls, which is especially useful on long pages (inspired by Google Mail and Drive).

[image]

It has come to light that this is having a small performance impact and causing some problems for developers, however I think that this is still possibly the best solution for users in this scenario.  I am open to suggestions on what others might perceive to be a better solution, could you please provide some?

- *CRUD stands for "Create, read, update and delete"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information given, your design seems like a very good one.  Being able to perform actions without scrolling back to the top of the page is an obvious benefit.

Functionality should not be dictated by what is easiest to develop.  Within reason, development should be driven by design, not the other way around.  And your proposed design is certainly within reason--the many websites that implement it show that it is possible and can perform well.

Answer (score 1):

I would have the Create button, near the top of the page (perhaps in a fixed/sticky bar, so always visible) as you mention.

Then if your design is a table of items which can each be read, updated or deleted. Have a column to the far right, with buttons for each action arranged horizontally. These could be simple text links, buttons or icons.

Comment: Agreed. All actions except "create" are performed on a specific item or items (if you allow bulk updates).